# Bypassing WindowsApps folder protection other than ACLs

Tags: windows, security, uwp

I noticed today that on windows 10 
some apps in the folder C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsApps... are protected in some way other than just the access permissions.

When installing Microsoft.MicrosoftEmulator_1.1.39.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe.msix or Microsoft.253890156C685_1.0.0.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe.Msix
as well as it seams other apps from the store

the Folders for those created in under C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsApps\ have some additional write protection.

While a cmd prompt started as TrustedInstaller can create and delete folders in the apps that come pre-installed in the folders fo these apps this fails with an access denied error.
Taking Ownership of those folders and files as well as adding full access permission does not solve the issue.

With a cmd prompt started as system it is at least possible to create or delete folders but for the existing folders created by the package installer its still not able to create a file within those.

This protection remains in place even when the system partition in question is mounted by an other windows 10 system.

The only way I found to gain full access to these files is to mount the partition in a windows 7 installation.

So it seams to me that MSFT has added som additional layer or patronizing the administrators which needs to be understood and broken.

Any ideas how to get around this issue?

Comment: You claim that there were some sort of protection that's not based on ACLs, but then continue to describe how the protection behaves under different user accounts. That all reads like the protection is based on ACLs. Why do you believe that it isn't?

Comment: Because when I set the ACL's such that my user has all access rights, and those should be able to write to those locations I still an not. So I have Full access according to the fodler's ACL, yet I still can not create a file inside that folder.

Comment: ACLs can also deny access. When there is a conflict between granted access and denied access, the deny rule takes precedence.

Comment: yes but there are no visible deny rules, just try it for your own try creating a file inside Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml_10.1808.3.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do? Windows protects these files to improve reliability. Even if you managed to change them, they are protected by signatures that will break and then the app will be remediated (re-downloaded from the Store).

Comment: > What are you ultimately trying to do?
does not mater, its a mater of principle, there must be no location on my system I can not write to if I so choose.
Its my PC and not Microsofts PC!

Comment: Cool. But seeing as the vast, vast majority of users would rather not have anything and everything being able to write everywhere and anywhere and stick virus' and malwhere wherever they please, that isn't going to happen.

Comment: This should be to be chosen by the user and not by a company that does not own the hardware.

Answer (score 3):

Well however the restrictions are implemented with this driver: https://github.com/DavidXanatos/IgnoreACLs you can gain access to everything everywhere.
With minor limitations, renaming of files in protected locations does not work and creating of directories.
Other than that, modifying, creating and deleting files and folders works fine.

Power back to the owners of the devices.

Comment: Glad you found something that worked for you. But as noted above, any modifications you make may be detected and remediated by the system.

Comment: Well if so than I will remediate that as well, my PC, I rule!